# Es posible poner el interprete de python escuchando en un puerto?

Tags: python, servidor

Es decir, que el python corra como un servicio en un puerto y poder mandarle sentencias de codigo, y que se valla ejecutando en esa maquina remota, oviamente, eso seria peligroso, pero es solo por curiosidad de si se puede hacer?
Algo asi por ejemplo:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 8435
(cliente): print("hola")
(servidor):  hola
```

Comment: Es posible con Pycharm Pro o Visual Studio Code. Mira [Remote Debugging Guide for Python](https://www.codementor.io/@jorgecolon/remote-debugging-in-python-v1cbnej91)

Comment: Puedes crear un *servidor HTTP* (por ejemplo con **http.server** o **flask**) o un *servidor WebSocket*. Si quieres ejecutarlo como un servicio te aconsejo [nssm](https://nssm.cc/). Te dejo un enlace de [cómo utilizar nssm con Python en español](https://tecnobillo.com/sections/python-en-windows/servicios-windows-python/servicios-windows-python.html).

Comment: No es exactamente a lo que me refiero, lo que quiero saber es se puede poner el mismo interprete de python u otro lenguaje a la escuha de comandos en  un puerto, y poder escribir codigo y recibir el resultado